# App responsiveness during loop

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have designed an app in vb.net 2005 that at one point adds and loops over about 500k list in listbox about.

When adding these items to the listbox, the app freezes for about 5-10 minutes, then when looping over the items, processing them, the app also freezes for the same time. Am loading the data from a text file

1. How can I make my application
   responsive during loops?
2. should I use a queue to process the
   list?
3. what is the messagequeue control
   for?

Comment: Your first question should really be what you are doing with 500k items in a UI in the first place. I don't believe that it can make sense to any user to deal with that amount of data.

Comment: so what do you recommend then as to how i deal with such amount of data?

Comment: If you have the items in a text file, load them into a list in UI only pick them up from there and process them, I would rather spawn an asynchronous operation that loads the info directly from the file and processes the items, every now and then emitting info to the UI to show the progress. But it's hard to give more specific advice without knowing the details of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). Store items in array, and bind listbox to it. Working with array will be **much** faster then with listbox'es collection.

Or you can call [BeginUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.beginupdate.aspx)/[EndUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.endupdate.aspx) before/after adding new items.

Comment: please a sample code on the BackgroundWorker with lisbox will be appreciated